# CakePHP without mod_rewrite causes 404 errors

Tags: cakephp, http-status-code-404, blogs

I'm pretty new to Cake, so I tryed to start with the blog tutorial.

I installed CakePHP 2.3.8 in webroot. 
Configured SQL and deleted all 3 .htaccess-files, cause i have no mod_rewrite. In core.php I activated 
    Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME')); 
I created the Posts-Model, Controller and the index-View like the tutorial says.

The APP/View/Pages/home.ctp tells me, everything's allright.

But when i try to open /posts/index i get a 404. Why?

Comment: Do you have controller with name post and index action inside this controller ?

Comment: I created the PostsController similiar to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without mod_rewrite the urls look like `www.example.com/index.php/controllername/actionname/param`, i.e. in your example you have to call `/index.php/posts/index` (or `/index.php/posts/`).

Comment: ok, thanks, it works. I'm just wondering, why this isn't part of the tutorial so far ...

Comment: Probably because most people are using mod_rewrite.