# Change root without change application with CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

This question is similar to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9485994/287948), but I am using full-URL, **no [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)**, see [cakephp **WITHOUT** mod_rewrite](http://wwdj.wijndaele.com/getting-started-with-cakephp-without-mod_rewrite/) or this "[sibling question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18054655/287948)".

I have a CakePHP folder that works well, at `/var/www/mycake` (localhost/mycake). Now I need change to  `/var/www/test/mycake` (localhost/test/mycake)... **HOW TO DO THIS CHANGE with minimal PHP code changes?**

---

I add a controller as Cake message recomended:

- TestMyCakeController.php ... nothing
- TestController.php  OK (!), but other error arrises

Comment: Do you want to add a second app to your cake core?  If not why not just place the entire cake structure app and core to the new directory?

Comment: I have `app` at `/var/www/test/mycake/app`... It is only one app, only one CakePHP structure... but not a host root, I need  to place all at `/var/www/test/`... So, not understand your comment.

Comment: Why not just move the app into that directory?  The ROOT is based on the directory that the top index.php file is in.  That's what the dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_) does.  I just tested with CakePHP 2.4.6 distribution and it appears to work.

Comment: @DavidH.Bennett, Yes... Perhaps  one thing or another... *1)* you mistaking, I need [cakephp **WITHOUT** mod_rewrite](http://wwdj.wijndaele.com/getting-started-with-cakephp-without-mod_rewrite/); *2)* Perhaps a good suggestion (!): to reinstall CakePHP and adapt it for my app's old CakePHP-v2.3.0 (!). Well... I'll do that this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Cake defines its ROOT directory in the root index.php file. If you look inside you'll see the following lines:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'mycake');
define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . '/' . 'test' . '/'. WEBROOT_DIR . '/');
```

Comment: Thanks (!) Not working: *"Warning: require(app/mycake/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory..."*. Not exist  `app/mycake/index.php`, only `app/index.php`.

Comment: Sorry, `Warning: require(app/mycake/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/test/mycake/index.php on line 49
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'app/mycake/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/test/mycake/index.php on line 49`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily move a CakePHP application to another directory under your web root.  The top level index.php contains the line:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

This will set the root directory to the current location of the main index.

Comment: Is a sub-case of the Ajay's answer, because I try and it not works... Remember that I need [cakephp **WITHOUT** mod_rewrite](http://wwdj.wijndaele.com/getting-started-with-cakephp-without-mod_rewrite/).